# Using Python to replace digits in an excel file

Tags: python, excel

Hi Im new to python and excel. I have a large data set and need to convert every number I have listed as "*10^" to"E"; such that 1.345*10^5 is converted to 1.345E5. I would like to try using a regular expression, but cannot get my replace fxn to work.

Comment: What have you tried? Show the regular expressions you have tried, and explain why they failed and then someone can help you tweak it rather than just giving you the answer.

Comment: Also: Excel treats *10^K the same as EK (the 2010 version, at least). If you just need it to display the numbers using engineering notation, you can mark the data and choose display type "Scientific".

Comment: Do you mean that you have `1.345*10^5` in an Excel cell as a TEXT value, not a NUMBER value? Or is your "large data set" not in Excel already?

Answer (score 0):

Working with Excel spreadsheets in Python may not be the best idea. Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, it may be worth converting the data to a .csv file using [csvkit](http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).

Here's a basic regex to get you started:

```
import re

data = '23*10^22, 12, 15.002, 12*10^98'
print re.sub('\*10\^', 'E', data)

# Returns 23E22, 12, 15.002, 12E98
```

This will simply substitute the characters `*10^` with `E`, which should do the trick.